# How many upgraded weapons can you have?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

In Fire Emblem Awakening you can upgrade weapons. How many of them you can have in your savegame?

Comment: I'm not certain if there is a limit on upgraded weapons specifically, but I do know there are some weapons which you cannot upgrade. If you do find a limit, please let us know!

Comment: You can have at least dozens of forged weapons, but based on online discussions it seems like there is a limit that is lower than a hundred.